# Angular reusable part of form in nested different formGroups

Tags: angular

I have problem. Because I want use several times part of form in different nested formgroup. But I don't know how.
Let's assume:

```
  data: new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(),
    age: new FormControl(),
    address: new FormGroup({
      city: new FormControl()
    }),
    parent: new FormArray([
      new FormGroup({
        address: new FormGroup({
          city: new FormControl()
        }),
      })
    ])
  })
```

For address i would like separate out new component or ng-template but always I have problem with **"Cannot find control with name:"**

Address section has many fields and I don't want copy/paste of template in form.
Is there any way to do this?

My problem in stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vxtakh?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Can you please recreate your issue in stackblitz?

Comment: Of course 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vxtakh?file=src/app/app.component.html